# I am able to fetch NSArray, NSStrings from class to another ViewController, but one array is always empty

Tags: objective-c

I have customer information and customer numbers that I'm getting from the server. I'm able to fetch this information to viewcontroller2. But, there is one array which is always empty when fetched from viewcontroller2. It is not empty when I fetch from the class(Customer.m). I'm sorry but I'm quite new to all this. I have spent now 4 days trying to work out where I have been going wrong. I have also looked at dozens of posts to try to find the answer. I have tried reading as much information as I can to learn what I'm missing but I just can't seem to make it work. Is there something I am missing? (I apologize in advance if there are some typing errors, I checked over it about ten times.)

This is Customer.m

```
    #import "Customer.h"

    @implementation Customer

    + (Customer *)sharedCustomer
    {
    static Customer *sharedCustomer;

    @synchronized(self)
    {
    if (!sharedCustomer)
        sharedCustomer = [[Customer alloc] init];

    return sharedCustomer;
    }
    }


-(void) GeneratefromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dict{
self.customernumber = dict[@"CustomerNumber"];
self.firstname = dict[@"firstname"];
self.lastname = dict[@"lastname"];
self.Nowappointments = dict[@"Nowappointments"];
self.FamilyAccounts = dict[@"FamilyAccounts"];
self.listoffutureAppointments = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.listofpastAppointments = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.FamilyAccountsArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

This is the code I'm using. (This is also Customer.m)

```
 NSArray *FamilyAccounts = [self.FamilyAccounts componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
 for (NSString* FamilyString in FamilyAccounts){

    NSLog(@"Print Family String%@",FamilyString);
 }
 NSArray *FamilyAccounts = [self.FamilyAccounts componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

 NSMutableArray* FamilyAccountssubArray = [FamilyAccounts mutableCopy];



NSNumber *CustomNumber2 = _CustomerNumber;
           [FamilyAccountssubArray addObject:CustomNumber2];

        NSMutableArray *CopyFamilyAccountArray = [FamilyAccountssubArray mutableCopy];

        NSArray *FamilyAccountsArray = [CopyFamilyAccountArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
                                    @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"intValue"
                                                                    ascending:NO]]];

        NSLog(@"sorted FamilyAccountsArray%@",FamilyAccountsArray);
```

This retrieves the array with no problems.

But when I try to get the FamilyAccountsArray in ViewController2, I always get an empty array.
But I'm able to retrieve the other arrays and strings.
For e.g FamilyAccounts, listoffutureAppointments. But not FamilyAccountsArray.

ViewController2

```
#import "ViewController2.h"
#import "Customer.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>

Customer *thiscustomer;
```

This works.

```
    NSMutableArray *PrintCustomer = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    PrintCustomer = thiscustomer.listoffutureAppointments;
    NSLog(@"Print the customer=%@",PrintCustomer);
```

This also works.

```
    NSArray *FamilyAccounts = [thiscustomer.FamilyAccounts componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

     NSLog(@"FamilyAccounts%@", FamilyAccounts);
```

This doesn't work in ViewController2. It always returns an empty array.

```
 NSArray *familyAccountsView2 = [thiscustomer.FamilyAccountsArray componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

     NSLog(@"familyAccountsView2=%@", familyAccountsView2);
```

Comment: Is `thiscustomer` nil when called in ViewController2? Also, why not using the `sharedInstance`? Instead of using `thiscustomer`, you should do `[Customer sharedInstace]`

Comment: `self.FamilyAccountsArray` (property) and `NSArray *FamilyAccountsArray` (local variable) are not the same `FamilyAccountsArray`. `thiscustomer.FamilyAccounts` and `thiscustomer.FamilyAccountsArray` are not the same property. Any build warnings?

Comment: @Larme "thiscustomer" is not nil when called in ViewController2. I can acces everything else except for "familyAccountsView2". I will try your suggestion, thank you.

Comment: @Willeke I'm sorry I changed the names a little to make it easier to read. But there are no build warnings. What do you mean not the same? In what way?

Comment: Post real code from a [mre] please.

Comment: Again, why is there `+ (Customer *)sharedCustomer` if you don't use it? What do you think it means? Also, why declare `Customer *thiscustomer;`like that? Why not let it be a property? Where is it "init" in ViewController2? Could you print it in ViewController1 and in Viewcontroller2? And give us the log?

Comment: @Willeke, working on making a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Larme, I'm researching what you said, I'll also post the logs when I finish the minimal reproducible example. I apologise I'm still quite new to this.

Comment: @Larme and Wileke After making a minified version, it is now working. The code is exactly the same, I only changed the names to make them more readable and it now works. I'm very confused. I'm trying to go through the code to understand why.

Comment: @Larme Is there something you recommend I read or look at to better understand your question? I thank both of you for your time.